# Keybaord is hiding the TextBox in Bottom Sheet in Android Jet PackCompose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicTextField
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Send
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

import androidx.compose.ui.layout.onGloballyPositioned
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.*
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import com.google.accompanist.insets.LocalWindowInsets

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable


fun BottomSheet(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
    val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
    val context = LocalContext.current


    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        val rootView = obtainRootView(context)

        val viewTreeObserver = rootView.viewTreeObserver
        val preDrawListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
            val isVisible = isKeyboardVisible(rootView)
            // Do something with the keyboard visibility if needed
            return@OnPreDrawListener true
        }

        viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(preDrawListener)

        onDispose {
            viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(preDrawListener)
        }
    }

    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() },
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        dragHandle = { /* Your drag handle */ },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()  // Adjust the height dynamically
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
                .padding(
                    bottom = with(LocalDensity.current) {
                        val rootView = obtainRootView(LocalContext.current)
                        if (isKeyboardVisible(rootView)) {
                            0.dp // Adjust the bottom padding as needed
                        } else {
                            0.dp
                        }
                    }
                )
        ) {
            // Your content, for example:
            CountryList()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Float.toDp(): Dp {
    return with(LocalDensity.current) { this@toDp.dp }
}

fun isKeyboardVisible(view: View): Boolean {
    val rect = Rect()
    view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
    val screenHeight = view.height
    val keypadHeight = screenHeight - rect.bottom
    return keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15 // Adjust the threshold as needed
}

fun obtainRootView(context: Context): View {
    return (context as? androidx.activity.ComponentActivity)?.window?.decorView ?: View(context)
}

@Composable
fun CountryList(
   ) {
    var textValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var isButtonEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val density = LocalDensity.current.density


    val countries = listOf(
        Pair("United States", "\uD83C\uDDFA\uD83C\uDDF8"),
        Pair("Canada", "\uD83C\uDDE8\uD83C\uDDE6"),
        Pair("India", "\uD83C\uDDEE\uD83C\uDDF3"),
        Pair("Germany", "\uD83C\uDDE9\uD83C\uDDEA"),
        Pair("France", "\uD83C\uDDEB\uD83C\uDDF7"),
        Pair("Japan", "\uD83C\uDDEF\uD83C\uDDF5"),
        Pair("China", "\uD83C\uDDE8\uD83C\uDDF3"),
        Pair("Brazil", "\uD83C\uDDE7\uD83C\uDDF7"),
        Pair("Australia", "\uD83C\uDDE6\uD83C\uDDFA"),
        Pair("Russia", "\uD83C\uDDF7\uD83C\uDDFA"),
        Pair("United Kingdom", "\uD83C\uDDEC\uD83C\uDDE7"),
    )

    LazyColumn {
        items(countries) { (country, flag) ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = 10.dp, horizontal = 20.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = flag,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 20.dp)
                )
                Text(text = country)
            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        // Big TextField
        BasicTextField(
            value = textValue,
            onValueChange = {
                textValue = it
                isButtonEnabled = it.isNotBlank()
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            singleLine = false,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    // Scroll to the end of the TextField when the content overflows
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                }
        )

        // Save Button
        Button(
            onClick = {
                if (isButtonEnabled) {
                    // onSaveClick(textValue)
                    textValue = ""
                    isButtonEnabled = false
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 16.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            enabled = isButtonEnabled
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Default.Send, contentDescription = "Save")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
            Text(text = "Save")

        }
    }

}
```